# How to retrieve database ID within Notion page?

Tags: notion-api

I have got a database table within a Notion page. I would like to use the Notion API to populate values to the database. However, since I have multiple of these pages it would be impractical to hardcode the database ID each time. Is there a way to retrieve the database ID within a Notion page via the Notion API? Or is there a way to find out what "objects" are within the page so that I can loop through them and find their attributes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database itself is a `block`, more precisely a `child_database`. You can obtain it's id by retrieving the child blocks of the page and filtering for `type = child_database`. I implemented this in Python a few weeks ago.

Utility methods

```
def _child_blocks(block_id, header, js):
    """
    Retrieves child blocks of a block from the notion api blocks endpoint
    :param block_id: id of the block to retrieve child blocks from (e.g. a page)
    :param header: authentication header for Notion api
    :param js: body of the query, generated by the jsons library
    :return: json of the response
    """
    read_url = f"https://api.notion.com/v1/blocks/{block_id}/children"

    res = requests.request("GET", read_url, headers=header, params=js)
    data = res.json()
    return data

def _empty_filter(next_cursor=None):
    """
    Json to query the appointments database for all entries, useful for pagination
    :param next_cursor: cursor to start from
    :return: json to use as body of a query
    """
    data = {
        "page_size": 30
    }
    if next_cursor:
        data["start_cursor"] = next_cursor
    return data
```

Final method

```
def _child_database(page_id, header) -> str:
    """
    Returns the database id of the first child database block
    :param page_id: id of the page to get the child database from
    :param header: authentication header for Notion api
    :return: database id of the first child database block, empty str if no child database block found
    """
    data = _child_blocks(page_id, header, _empty_filter())
    while True:
        for result in _results(data):
            if result['type'] == 'child_database':
                item_database_id = result['id']
                return item_database_id
        if not data['has_more']:
            break
        data = _child_blocks(page_id, header, _empty_filter(data['next_cursor']))
    return ""
```